# Limitations about override model entity

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, overrides, model

**I thought I was quite familiar now with plugins and preferences to override built-in behavior of Magento 2.**

However it seems not, and I have a question, is there some particular technical limitations with overriding by preference (on top of that provided in the official documentation) ?. **Or any tips?**

**My example:** I created a custom category attribute. As there is some treatment to process before displaying it, I created a Category model in my module, make it inherit the original one, defined my getter for the custom attribute, defined the preference in `di.xml`.

However, this time it's not working. Instead of preference on the category interface I have to make preference on the model to make it work. **Is there a particular technical reason?**

My example is when the user access to a category page in the front office.

Thanks.!

**EDIT** :

So, according to your recommendation, I set the di.xml in front end, without success. Hence, there is my code:

*etc/module.xml*

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.2">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

*etc/frontend/di.xml*

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Category" />
```

My *Model/Category.php* contructor:

```
public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Api\CategoryUrlRepositoryInterface $categoryUrlRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
    AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryAttributeRepositoryInterface $metadataService,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Tree $categoryTreeResource,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\TreeFactory $categoryTreeFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory $storeCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filter,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $flatState,
    \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
    UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder,
    \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
    CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $extensionFactory, $customAttributeFactory, $storeManager, $metadataService,
        $categoryTreeResource, $categoryTreeFactory, $storeCollectionFactory, $url, $productCollectionFactory,
        $catalogConfig, $filter, $flatState, $categoryUrlPathGenerator, $urlFinder, $indexerRegistry, $categoryRepository, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);

    $this->categoryUrlRepositoryInterface = $categoryUrlRepositoryInterface;
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting while override model using preference?

Comment: I don't have any error: if I use preference on the CategoryInterface, it simply doesn't work. To make it work, I have to do it on the Model. And as far I know (correct me if I am wrong), in dependency injection with service contract, I have to preference with the interface, not the model.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in your question to be sure, but my guess is that this is likely a load order issue. I've run into these before with `di.xml` files. Make sure that your di.xml is located in an appropriate area folder, if necessary. It can be in the main `etc/` directory but do know that it will be overwritten by area-specific DI.

So, for example, if your file is in `etc/`, and the Magento one is in `etc/frontend`, the Magento one will take precedence. If they're both in the same directory level (e.g., `etc/frontend`), I suggest making your module depend on the `Magento_Catalog` module to ensure that it is loaded after the `Magento_Catalog` module.

Comment: No effects. I posted my code as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Post your di.xml and constructor class code that handles dependencies.

Looks like there is some issue in your created module. 
Updated after code posted :
Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface  for this I dont see where this has been injected in constructor class.You need to place this as an argument in Constructor

Comment: Do you mean that it may be a constructor issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you checkout the constructor for the following class: *Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository*, you can see, it is using the **Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory** as argument.

That is why your preference set on the CategoryInterface does not work.

If instead it would have been **Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterfaceFactory** it would have worked.

You can make the test by changing its constructor and you will see it works if you replace it by the **CategoryInterfaceFactory** and apply your previous preference.

Comment: OK thanks. But I don't want (and never have to) change core files. So is there a solution for me to respect the service contract or am I stuck?

Comment: No idea? It is strange that it couln't be done.